# Remove row from arbitrary dimension in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, numpy-ndarray

I have a function, `remrow` which takes as input an arbitrary numpy nd array, `arr`, and an integer, `n`. My function should remove the last row from `arr` in the `n`th dimension. For example, if call my function like so:

`remrow(arr,2)`

with `arr` as a 3d array, then my function should return:

`arr[:,:,:-1]`

Similarly if I call;

`remrow(arr,1)`

and `arr` is a 5d array, then my function should return:

`arr[:,:-1,:,:,:]`

My problem is this; my function must work for all shapes and sizes of `arr` and all compatible `n`. How can I do this with numpy array indexing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Construct an indexing tuple, consisting of the desired combination of slice(None) and slice(None,-1) objects.

```
In [75]: arr = np.arange(24).reshape(2,3,4)
In [76]: idx = [slice(None) for _ in arr.shape]
In [77]: idx
Out[77]: [slice(None, None, None), slice(None, None, None), slice(None, None, None)]
In [78]: idx[1]=slice(None,-1)
In [79]: arr[tuple(idx)].shape
Out[79]: (2, 2, 4)
In [80]: idx = [slice(None) for _ in arr.shape]
In [81]: idx[2]=slice(None,-1)
In [82]: arr[tuple(idx)].shape
Out[82]: (2, 3, 3)
```

Comment: Hmm I see - thank you! I am curious - why does the output on 77 give `slice(None, None, None)`, when you specified only `slice(None)` on 76?